# Incopatible Pointer to integer conversion sending nsstring to parameter of type 'NSUIInteger'

Tags: iphone, nsinteger

i am getting this warning "Incopatible Pointer to integer conversion sending nsstring to parameter of type 'NSUIInteger' (aka unsigned Int)" in the below statement how to resolve this please guide Thanks in advance.

```
    DetailTitLbl.text=[lat_long_Array objectAtIndex:parTbl.placemark_Title];
```

parTbl.placemark_Title--> is of type string stored in the core data table.
Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _incopatible_ or _incompatible_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DetailTitLbl.text=[lat_long_Array objectAtIndex:[parTbl.placemark_Title intValue]];
```

Try this

Comment: yes thanks for the quick reply..and one more doubt how can i update the label(i have only one label) when i click the detail disclosure button on the mk annotation,that label should display the place name(i stored in the core data table),then if i click on another disclosure button it should update the place name on that label.

Comment: Can any one give me idea about this.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Method 'objectAtIndex' must has the argument that is NSInteger.

You can trasform that variable.

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]
 NSInteger index = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:parTbl.placemark_Title] intValue]
 DetailTitLbl.text=[lat_long_Array objectAtIndex:index];
```